# Can we queue up Docusign create envelope calls (.net)

Tags: .net, docusignapi

We want to have thru our app a way for the user to request a document to be sent out, supply the recipients name and email, place this request in a queue that we will service. Every n minutes, we'll look in the queue and grab whatever needs to be sent out to docusign. It looks like the minute you create an envelope via the api, it is already on the docusign server in the draft status. I guess what I could do is have my own envelope class object that I populate and then when it goes in the queue, it would then be made into a docusign envelope to get sent out. I don't think there's another way to do this. Anyone with a better idea than this?

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely doable and no need for a special envelope class. I have 2 apps, one creates the envelope and the other one sends it off. The one doing the create never tries to connect to docusign. The sending app does connect. It takes each envelope in the queue and set the status to "sent" and off it went.